# Unix command to strip off part of a line

Tags: svn, shell, unix, command-line, grep

I'm working with command-line SVN.  Coming from TortoiseSVN on Windows, I found it very tedious whenever I try to pick one specific file to revert, diff, commit, etc., when the path is very long like this:

```
src/com/company/stuff/platform/appname/subpackage/subsubpackage/Foo.java
```

If I want to do a diff on this file, I have to type all this:

```
svn diff src/com/company/stuff/platform/appname/subpackage/subsubpackage/Foo.java
```

so, I try to grep that by doing this:

```
svn st | grep Foo
```

But it returns:

```
M       src/com/company/stuff/platform/appname/subpackage/subsubpackage/Foo.java
```

Now, how do I strip off the "M        " part, so I can get just the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I'd use `awk`:

```
svn st | awk '/Foo/ { print $2 ; }'
```

`awk` takes scripts with *matching* instructions and blocks of code to execute on the lines that match. This matches lines with `Foo` in them and prints the second field. (Using the default `FS` field-separator, which should split on tabs and spaces.)

You should also look into the filename completion abilities of your shell; most newer shells include the ability to complete partially-typed filenames. For your long example:

```
src/com/company/stuff/platform/appname/subpackage/subsubpackage/Foo.java
```

I'd probably type it like this:

```
src/com/com<tab>/stuff/pla<tab>/appn<tab>/subp<tab>/subsub<tab>/Foo<tab>
```

You might need to type more or less depending upon what files are in your directories.

Comment: I did the tabs, and that's also tedious. type-tab-slash-type-tab-slash -... Your solution seems the most elegant. No grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn st | grep Foo | sed 's/M *//'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
svn st | grep Foo | sed 's/^[A-Z]\s*//'
```

Comment: After playing around with sed, I come up with `sed 's/. *//'` which also works with the uncommited files ('?').

Comment: @alnite Do remember to put the `^` character to tell `sed` that only look for that at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If 'svn st' always returns an (unwanted) first column, and then the path, try this:

```
svn st | grep Foo | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: this looks like the cleaner way.